# External Insertion Sort On a Binary File

Tags: java, insertion-sort, external-sorting

I am trying to preform an external insertion sort on a binary file full of random doubles between 0 and 1. I added a bunch of println statements after "value" and "temp" are assigned and it looks like they are getting the same value each iteration. I don't think I am traversing the file correctly.

```
public class ExternalFileSort 
{

    public static void sort(String filename, int length) throws IOException
    {
        int i, j;
        double value, temp;


        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");

        for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            file.seek(i);
            temp = file.readDouble();

            j = i-1;
            file.seek(j);
            value = file.readDouble();


            while (j >= 0 && value > temp)
            {
                file.seek(j+1);
                file.writeDouble(value);
                j--;
            }

            file.seek(j+1);
            file.writeDouble(temp);

        }


        file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: **What** is an *external* insertion sort?

Comment: What makes you think that you do not traverse the file correctly? Do you have a testcase that your code fails?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch reading in two doubles at a time from a binary file, sorting them, and writing them back to the file.

Comment: @KendallLacy I have never seen that attempted before. Merge sort is `n log n`, while insertion sort is `n*n`. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @user2040251 No it does not fail. The final file seems to have multiples of one value.

Comment: Homework? Doing insertion sort on a file is going to be *horrifyingly* slow and inefficient.

Comment: you seek by increments of 1, but you write doubles, which require 8 byte to write.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It is homework.

Comment: When you insert, you need to shift the *entire rest of the file* to make room for the value you're inserting.

Comment: the only way you can have something half-decent for insertion-sorting a file is by searching in the file for the smallest value, and *swapping* the current value with that value. Otherwise you'll have to shift everything.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have doubles written in your file according to that definition (that is a mandatory prerequisite) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeDouble%28double%29

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
long currentPosition = 0L;
while (currentPosition < file.length()) {
    double current = file.readDouble();
    double min = current;
    long minPosition = currentPosition;
    // Find the smallest value in the rest of the file
    while (currentPosition < file.length()) {
        double candidate = file.readDouble();
        if (candidate < min) {
            min = candidate;
            minPosition = file.getFilePointer() - 8;
        }
    }
    // Swap
    file.seek(minPosition);
    file.writeDouble(current);
    file.seek(currentPosition);
    file.writeDouble(min);
    currentPosition = file.getFilePointer();
}
```

Not tested, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should know is that the `double` type uses 8 bytes. If your file is a binary array of doubles, the first 8 bytes will correspond to the first double, the next 8 bytes to the second double and so on. If you try reading a double after performing a `file.seek(1)`, for example, you will read a messed up value because it would be composed by 7 bytes of the first double and the first byte of the second.
It would be a lot easier and more efficient to first read the entire file into an array of doubles, perform the sort algorithm in the array and then writing the resulting array back to the disk. For the first part you would calculate the number of doubles using `int size = file.length() / 8;`. Then you would create an array of doubles with this size and read them with the corresponding number of `file.readDouble()` calls.
If you absolutely have to do the entire operation directly on the binary file, don't forget that the real positions of doubles inside of the file should be multiplied by 8 on seek operations so they are converted into byte positions. Ex: the fist double would be at position 0, the second at 8, the third at 16 and so on.